# Choice of miniature in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm looking for how to create a hole in transparent background like this
[choose miniature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9WXO.png)

I made an animation of a circle inside a transparent background (which is above the picture) using PanResponder, and now I don't know how to create this circle not transparent

Maybe there is a way to do it differently?

```
const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: () => {
        pan.setOffset({
          x: pan.x._value,
          y: pan.y._value
        });
      },
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(
        [
          null,
          { dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y }
        ],
        {useNativeDriver:false}
      ),
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        pan.flattenOffset();
      }
    })
  ).current;



return (
<ImageBackground source={{ uri: images[active].uri }} style={styles.image}>
      <View style={styles.imageBackground}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          transform: [{ translateX: pan.x }, { translateY: pan.y }]
        }}
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
          <View
            style={styles.circle}
          />
      </Animated.View>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground> )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably use react-native-svg for this.